# Get max value in JS for filtered array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like:

```
var myArr = [{
    number: 5,
    shouldBeCounted: true
}, {
    number: 6,
    shouldBeCounted: true
}, {
    number: 7,
    shouldBeCounted: false
}, ...];
```

How to find max `number` for objects with `shouldBeCounted` set to `true`? I don't want to use loops, just wondering if this is possible with `Math.max.apply` (or something like this).

Comment: No it's not possible. You can `Math.max` with `.map` like so http://jsfiddle.net/nqx7ghzx/

Comment: @Alexander And you're writing this in a comment instead of an answer... because?

Comment: What if all the elements have `shouldBeCounted` `false`

Comment: is there a particular reason you want to allow apply and not loop ? I think any answer is gonna make a kind of loop over your object for this.

Comment: is there a reason for the restriction? ie. loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not possible. You can use `Math.max` with `.map` like so

```js
var myArr = [{
    number: 5,
    shouldBeCounted: true
}, {
    number: 6,
    shouldBeCounted: true
}, {
    number: 7,
    shouldBeCounted: false
}];


var max = Math.max.apply(Math, myArr.map(function (el) {
    if (el.shouldBeCounted) {
        return el.number;
    }
    
    return -Infinity;
}));

console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 2):

With a simple `.reduce()`:

```js
var myArr = [{
  number: 5,
  shouldBeCounted: true
}, {
  number: 6,
  shouldBeCounted: true
}, {
  number: 7,
  shouldBeCounted: false
}];

var max = myArr.reduce(function(max, current) {
  return current.shouldBeCounted ? Math.max(max, current.number) : max;
}, -Infinity);

console.log(max);
```

Where

- `myArr.reduce()` - Reduces an array to a single value. Accepts a function with two parameters, the current cumulative value, and the current item (also two more optional parameters for the index of the item, and the original array).
- `return current.shouldBeCounted ? Math.max(max, current.number) : max;` - For each item, returns the current max is shouldBeCounted is false, or the max between the current known max and the current number.
- `, -Infinit` - Starting with `-Infinity`.

The advantage of this approach over the one in the accepted answer is that this will only iterate the array once, while `.filter()` and `.map()` loop over the array once each.

Comment: If all numbers are negative, this returns `5e-324` (oddly enough).  Replacing `Number.MIN_VALUE` with `-Infinity` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Another less verbose solution (if your numbers are all positive):

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, myArr.map(function(el) {
    return el.number*el.shouldBeCounted;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. All solutions require walk the array unless you will be storing max number in a variable before adding to the array.

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to get the number, then you can try:

```js
let myArr = [
  { number: 5, shouldBeCounted: true},
  { number: 6, shouldBeCounted: true},
  { number: 7, shouldBeCounted: false}
];

function maxNum(mArr) {
  return  Math.max(...mArr.filter(a => a.shouldBeCounted ).map( o => o.number))
}
console.log(maxNum(myArr))
```